# Android Studio 4.0 : Build Failed | Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradle

I recently downloaded Android Studio 4.0 in my 64 bit Windows machine with 8.1 Windows OS. I am not able to build any application on it. I get the following error. The `Windows Universal C Runtime` is already installed in my system. I have tried so many other solutions suggested in other threads but none of them worked for me and I cannot figure out a possible course.

```
> * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s
16 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

Answer (score -2):

I was getting the same error with Android studio 4.1 after an update. Disabling Gradle offline mode solved the issue for me.

Comment: @TominBAzhakathu .. have you checked the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62718297/8928024). I'm noy familiar at current topic so please validate if OP's answer might be where the issue comes from...